# Spring and Hibernate inside Axis2 inside Tomcat6

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, tomcat, apache-axis

I'm try to create web service base on axis2 (without a ServletContext). I have code that work properly (Spring + Hebirnate) and try to put it into AAR as it describe in [this article](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_4_1/spring.html)  and [this one](http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/2009/01/old-school-apache-axis2-web-services.html) . All work good except hibernate.

I have:

```
    <bean id="dataSourceCommon" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:oci:@xxxx" />
  <property name="username" value="xxxx" />
  <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
  <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
  <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceCommon" />

  <property name="mappingLocations">
   <value>classpath:xxxx.hbm.xml</value>
  </property>

  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    </prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="hibernateDaoSupport" abstract="true"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
 </bean>
```

This file in root of AAR.

I copy this aar-file into `c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\axis2\WEB-INF\services`, but if I try to run Tomcat server I get error:

> ```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> ```
>
> Error creating bean with name
>   'hibernateSessionFactory' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [xxxx.context.xml]: Instantiation of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Could not instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested
>   exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>       ...
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

**where my mistake?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

then the mistake is that you did not include the Hibernate classes (hibernate.jar, etc) on the claspath of your webapp (`WEB-INF/lib`).

Comment: Oh yes!
So easy! Befoure I added *jar file only in AAR\lib!
Now all work!